# Why can't I attach an MDF file to SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've tried using SSMS but when I click Attach I get error File Not Found. This is `AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf`. There is no LDF file. I tried exec'ing this as well:

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='AdventureWorks2012',
     @physname = N'R:\SqlServer\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf'
GO
```

but I get the same error:

> failed with the operating system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.).

Comment: Do you have any log file? or do you have missing log file?

Comment: If you want to attach without the `.ldf`, just highlight and "remove" the log file in the attach wizard

Comment: no log file, as far as I know.

Comment: I followed the directions here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1894/attach-a-sql-server-database-with-a-missing-transaction-log-file/ and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

TRY the below snippet and you will be through without a .ldf file.

```
    create database AdventureWorks2012_Data
    on
    (FILENAME='D:\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf')
    FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
    GO
```